# Javascript sorting a 2D array based on condition

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating the distance from points to the origin. It's a basic math calculation: `Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x-0, 2) + Math.pow(y-0, 2) )`

For testing, I have the points: `points = [[1,3],[-2,2]]`. I would like to sort it based on the smallest distance to the origin.

My code:

```
points.sort((a,b) => {
        const d1 = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(a[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1], 2) ); 
        const d2 = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b[0], 2) + Math.pow(b[1], 2) ); 
        return d1 <= d2 ? a-b : b-a; 
});

console.log(points);
```

The log is showing: `[[1,3],[-2,2]]` The 2D array is not changing. The calculation is right in the sort function. I'm not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the delta of the distances.

```js
var points = [[1, 3], [-2, 2]];

points.sort((a, b) => {
  const d1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a[0], 2) + Math.pow(a[1], 2));
  const d2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b[0], 2) + Math.pow(b[1], 2));
  return d1 - d2;
});

console.log(points);
```

An even shorter approach uses [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot).

```js
var points = [[1, 3], [-2, 2]];

points.sort((a, b) => Math.hypot(...a) - Math.hypot(...b));

console.log(points);
```

Comment: I'm don't clearly understand how the sort() method works. Could you explain why I need to take the delta?

Comment: I think I don't get what needs to be returned in the sort() method to sort an array

Comment: @myTest532myTest532, maybe you have a look here first: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). the expected result of the callback should return a value smaller than zero, if the first is smaller than the second item, zero for same items and greater than zero for all other items.